# Building JUnit 5 from Source in eclipse on Windows

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build, junit5

I'm currently using JUnit 5.1, but I want to switch to JUnit 5.5 (at least 5.4) to use new features of that version (mainly the `@Order` annotation), but I'm really struggling to properly set it up.
Unfortunately I cannot simply switch to a newer eclipse version, because I'm tied a specific version we use at my workplace.

As there is no JAR-download, i've tried to build it from source. The only guidelines concerning this are saying to [build it with Gradle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5#building-from-source), but I don't understand how to do this.

What I tried so far:
- downloaded the repository as an archive (zip) and imported it to eclipse, which resulted in multiple projects and <1.000 errors
- imported the repository into eclipse (via import wizard), but failed to find a way to make a build from it

I was able to run some test with JUnit 5.4 features, but i achieved this by downloading different modules as JARs from some maven-repository I found in a [JUnit issue on github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/146) and including them as external JARs into the classpath. This was very tedious because of the number of different JARs & the way they were organized in the repository folders. 
To me this feels like a workaround, as I still have no idea how to solve the initial problem of building JUnit from source.

I'm quite new to eclipse and have a basic understanding of what Gradle is, but I've never used it so far.
I don't expect a detailed step-by-step guide on how to achieve this (although I wouldn't complain ;) ), but I'd really appreciate it, if you could give me an outline of how building from source is done in general and maybe additional references for me to read about certain steps (e.g. setting up gradle).

Comment: I don’t really understand why you want to build it. All you have to do is change the dependency in your gradle, maven or ant file to the version you want. My guess is that you should first learn how to set up a project in Eclipse with Gradle or Maven. As soon as you’ve mastered that switching to the version of your choice will be a piece of cake.

Comment: @johanneslink Allright. I wanted to get familiar with Gradle at some point anyway, so I guess I'll check out how it works.

Comment: You can also download the jars from maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter -> click on library -> click on version -> files - jar. But please, use maven/gradle/anything else.